# How do I covert videos for a Nokia mobile using Arista transcoder?

Tags: video-conversion, nokia

I am new in ubuntu and need some help. I have **11.04** installed

How do I covert videos for a Nokia mobile using **Arista transcoder**?

Specifically, I need my videos to be compatible with my **Nokia 5xxx**

Answer (score 0):

In the software center run a search for "arista" which will result in an item like the one shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

Simply click in the button that reads "Install" (in my case is already installed, that's why my button reads "Remove").

Good luck!